# Debian, ftp user with access to /var/www

Tags: debian, ftp, webserver, web, proftpd

I want to have ftp user who have only access to `/var/www` and work on all of files, but the problems arise when I give permission to `/var/www`, exactly `chown`. I try with `chgrp` but then I cannot edit files. I hope that you see my problem, so can I please you to give me some advice how to solve my problem or give me other solution.

I am using `apache2`, `php5`, `mysql` and `proftpd`.

Comment: do scp with your user.

Comment: scp, what you mean

Comment: ssh as an associated program called scp to transfer files. http://askubuntu.com/questions/280093/how-do-i-copy-files-with-scp-to-var-www

Comment: Have you already gone thru [proftpd configuration](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Directory.html)?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way, I did it:

- create new user *newftpuser*:

  > adduser newftpuser
- create new group *caneditwww*:

  > addgroup caneditwww
- add *newftpuser* to that group:

  > usermod -a -G caneditwww newftpuser
- change group ownership for all files and dirs in /var/www:

  > chgrp -R caneditwww /var/www
- modify group permissions on /var/www, so
  group members can modify the content:

  > chmod -R g+w /var/www
- optionally mount directory /var/www to home directory of newftpuser:

  > mkdir /home/newftpuser/www
  >   mount /var/www /home/newftpuser/www -o
  >   bind`

Now, after login, *newftpuser* can edit everything in /var/www, which he finds in /home/newftpuser/www.

Comment: This is almost certainly a horrible idea. What if you have more sites set up in `/var/www`? This is standard practice on large servers. You have now given write access to _everything_ to that one user and anyone else in the new group.